# How to Mock variable which is initialised to a new Object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am testing a **OnPostAsync()** method which deals with registration of a new user. When the test runs through method it encounters many variables and that is where I have issues e.g. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. **I get the error at `var user`, I already have `CreateAsync()` mocked. I left out the code for simplicity** Any help would be much appreciated!

### Register.cshtml.cs

```
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public RegisterModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
        IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = "tester@gmail.com", Email = "tester@gmail.com" };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "falafelsrock");

        if (result.Succeeded)
        { 
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded");
        }
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }
    }
}
}
```

### RegisterModelTests.cs

```
[TestFixture]
public class RegisterModelTests
{
    private Mock<FakeUserManager> _mockUserManager;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _mockUserManager = new Mock<FakeUserManager>();
        SetUpFakeUserManager();
    }

    public RegisterModel CreateRegisterModel()
    {
        return new RegisterModel(_mockUserManager.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("tester@tester.co.uk")]
    public async Task GivenValidInput_OnPostAsync_CreatesANewUser(string email)
    {
        // Arrange
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
        var unitUnderTest = CreateRegisterModel();
        // Act
        var result = await unitUnderTest.OnPostAsync("/asdsad/asda");
        // Assert
        if (result != null)
            Assert.Pass();
    }

    private void SetUpFakeUserManager()
    {
        _mockUserManager.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>(), It.IsAny<string>())
            .ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Input.Email`? The other thing is user in setup and actual code are different as they are created with `new` keyword. It is different instance...

Comment: Your `Input` class is what is known as 'ambient context' which is bad when it comes to isolating your code for testing, since it needs to exist and if it has any functionality, you're testing that as well. It would be better if you injected the `Input` class sinch you could then set it up in your test.

Comment: @Johnny Input is just a property of type InputModel, InputModel simply holds three string fields: name, email and password. Which is why in my test I simply used those strings.

Comment: @HansKilian the input class in this instance represents just three strings, which is why I interchanged them with my own hard coded strings. Do you know how I can prevent the error from happening? That is my sole concern right now

Comment: @steve Does it still fail in the `var user = ...` statement after you changed it to hard-coded strings?

Comment: @HansKilian no it doesn't! It follows through the code and now fails somewhere else. I will update the code here as well! Thanks I get what you meant above

Comment: @HansKilian how would I inject it through the OnPostAsync() method?

Comment: @steve If you use a dependency injection framework, I can show you. I'd like to see the constructor for the controller then. Can you add that to your post?

Comment: @HansKilian thanks so much for the idea! I did some reading and implemented it myself and it seems to work. I simply added **InputModel as a transient service** then passed it into the constructor and initialised it. Does that sound like what you would have done? :)

Comment: I just can't think of how I would do it for the callbackUrl as Url and Request are properties of the PageModel class :/

Comment: @steve Yes, that's what I would do. The thing you want to be able to do is to use one `Input` in your test and another in the running code.

Comment: @HansKilian thanks i've achieved that through the mocking. How do I get around `Url.Page()`? as that is essentially `RegisterModel.Url.Page()`. I thought of mocking a registermodel like the fakeusermanager and setup the `Page()` method to return a string but that would mean having to pass a **registerModel** through the **registermodel** constructor which doesn't make sense right?